# hiding secret key in django project on github after uploading project

Tags: python, django, github, secret-key

I uploaded my django project on github and I have a lot of commits on my project.

I don't want to delete my project and reupload it again.

what is the easiest way to hide secret key after uploading project to github and after a lot of commits?

Comment: is that a public repo or private?

Comment: You should be setting the secret key with something like `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'oweugnweufgnw')` anyway; that way you set a different secret key on every environment you run it on, and simply have a meaningless default value in your repo.

Comment: use python-decouple and keep your keys in a `.env` and don't forget to put .env in .gitignore! https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the same directory where `manage.py` is, create a file whose name is `.env`, and put inside it:

```
SECRET_KEY = '....your secret key ....' # --- the one indicated in your settings.py, cut an paste it here
```

where `SECRET_KEY = '....your secret key ....'` is the one indicated in your `settings.py`. 
So cut this line from your `settings.py` and paste it in the `.env` file.

In the same directory, create a file whose name is `.gitignore`, and put inside it:

```
.env
```

Then in your `settings.py`, where previously you had `SECRET_KEY = '....your secret key ....'`, put:

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY") # this is to replace the secret key you cut away before
```

then in your command prompts run:

```
pip install python-decouple
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

then add, commit and push on Github.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) you can find out more information on how **.gitignore** works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create File => .env
2. Cut this from settings.py =>

   SECRET_KEY = '-----your secret key-----'
3. Paste in .env
4. Write this in settings.py =>

   from decouple import config

   SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")
5. Write this in terminal or cmd =>

   pip install python-decouple
6. Then write this in terminal or cmd =>

   pip freeze > requirements.txt
7. Go in cPanel and upload File .env